# Accidentally deleted /var/mail in OSX

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

Actually I just wanted to remove username folder in `/var/mail/<username>`

But I forget to add `/` at the end of `/var/mail`, making it into `sudo rm -R /var/mail <username>`

The question is...

Since it's just a directory, can I just do `sudo mkdir /var/mail`?

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a folder you can recreate it by doing

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/mail
```

Also make sure it has the **right permissions** *(based on my own permissions, default on OSX)*

```
$ sudo chown root:mail /var/mail
$ sudo chmod 775 /var/mail
```